# SP2013 special chars broken in HTML page layout

Tags: 2013, page-layout, html, special-characters

I'm creating some page layouts for my custom .master in a SP2013 Publishing SC. 
There are some hard coded texts in the layout. Since it's for a German client there will be some special chars like `äöüß`.

I can use these chars without problems in the HTML .master and they are displayed correctly. But if I'm using them in a page layout, the chars are broken. I assume that they are received broken from the IIS, due the fact that the chars I placed in the HTML .master work properly.

It makes no difference if I use `ü &uuml;` or `&#252;` -> all are converted by SP to `ü`. It's written in the created .aspx page layout. The output is still `Ã¼`.

I tried following solutions

1. Saving the HTML in different encodings
2. Setting the IIS .NET Globalization settings to utf-8
3. Multiple restarts and IIS resets
4. Creating a new SC
5. Using encoded chars
6. Putting `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the page layouts head (it is already in the HTML .master)

Does someone have any suggestions ?

### **Edit**

Have a look at my answer - hope i can spare you from wasting your time on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### I fixed it after wasting frustrating hours on this !

Its quite easy but doesnt make sense.

Just add the HTML 4.1 (not HTML 5 - it wont work) char encode tag to the additional pagehaed placeholder, and it works like a charm. Make sure that you've tried the other solutions, may it's the result of a combination.

Fact is, that it is already included in the .master, but the IIS wont return the right HTML if not specified again by the page layout.

Here's my ContentPlaceholder for the additional PageHead:

```
 <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">-->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <!--CS: Ausschnitt Bearbeitungsmodusbereich starten-->
        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
        <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="Publishing" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
        <!--MS:<Publishing:EditModePanel runat="server" id="editmodestyles">-->
            <!--MS:<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/editmode15.css %&#62;" After="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/pagelayouts15.css %&#62;" runat="server">-->
            <!--ME:</SharePoint:CssRegistration>-->
        <!--ME:</Publishing:EditModePanel>-->
        <!--CE: Ende Ausschnitt Bearbeitungsmodusbereich-->
 <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
```